# How to connect to (Plesk Obsidian) database

Tags: database, symfony, plesk

I'm trying to connect to my Abonnement Database 'mydatabase' under the localhost.

telnet localhost 3306 is working and connects successfully.

symfony tells me the following error: 'An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution'

if I try to connect without a password it finds the server gives me the correct error message. What is the correct way to connect to Database in Plesk?

Symfony .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://dbuser:dbpass@localhost:3306/mydatabase
```

Comment: You don't give a lot of details on you local environment. Are you using Symfony's local webserver?

Comment: Sorry, i dont know Whats Good to know. But no, i dont use The symfony dev Server. Its a apache and in local environment works without errors.

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Yes i tried this and the global ip with and without port

Comment: And what is the error message when using an IP address? It should be different from the one you posted since that one mentions name resolution.

Comment: Its the same buuuuuuuut, i believe im very near to the solution. Its possible that my password use incorrect letters... i try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching many hours i find the solution:

My Database password had incorrect Characters, in my case $ and ?. I think '?' is not allowed in my case. After change the password all is going fine.

Thx for reading and i hope someone need this info as helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected something like that, if you don't want to change your password, you might want to try to url encode your dsn  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62501100/4346453